# reverse calls order in fork

Tags: linux, fork

Warm greetings,
I wrote these lines which display 4 messages corresponding to 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D' with a for loop and fork. I would like to reverse the calls (output becomes 'D' 'C' 'B' 'A') by making the parent process wait for the children to execute first.

**Initial code (right order from A to D):**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
int i;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if (fork()){
    break;
 }
 printf("Mon nom est %c. Je viens du processus %d\n",'A'+i,getpid());
 }
 return(0);
 }
```

My code for the desired output (from D to A):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
int i;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if (fork()){
    wait(NULL);
    break;
 }
printf("Mon nom est %c. Je viens du processus %d\n",'A'+i,getpid());
}
return(0);
 }
```

I added **wait(NULL)** but it doesn't seem to help.
I thank you all in advance!!

Comment: If you don't want the parent process to do anything until the child process it just spawned ends, then why are you forking at all?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, could you elaborate further?

Comment: Why are you using `fork` at all in this program? Is it homework?

Comment: It is. I am asked to give the process tree of the first code snippet. That I figured out. Then, I am supposed to edit the program in order to reverse the order of the calls.

Comment: Your initial code is certainly not guaranteed to print in the order you expect.   Indeed, it may print more than 4 lines.  Try running it with the output piped to `cat` or redirected to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Lets trace `i` between the processes:

```
P0:i=0; fork(); wait(); exit();
        P1: i=0; printf(); i = 1; fork(); wait(); exit();
                                  P2: i=1; printf(); i=2; fork(); wait(); exit();
```

See the pattern; the parent is always `wait()`ing and `exit()`ing without printing.   The child prints in the parents place, then becomes the parent of the next generation.

Not to be too picky about style, but even such a small program can benefit from a structured indentation:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        if (fork()) {
            wait(NULL);
            break;
        }
        printf("Mon nom est %c. Je viens du processus %d\n",'A'+i,getpid());
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :)